# Mongo DB - Sort and Skip within a group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB and I want to sort and skip records within a group.

Below is a sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51cd7274267d959cb9f95cea"),
    "creation_time" : 100,
    "delivered" : true,
    "id" : 1,
    "user_id" : 10
}
```

Now what I want is the `_id` of all the documents per user (`user_id`) where no. of documents for a user is greater than 4. Also I want the `_id` of  documents after skipping those 4 documents. So if a user has 6 documents, then I want the `_id` of last 2 documents (sorted by creation_time) so that I can archive those 2 old documents to another db.

I am using the following query:

```
db.newsdb.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        delivered: true
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            user_id: "$user_id",
            creation_time: "$creation_time"
        }
    }
}
])
```

Now the problem is that I want to perform `$sort` and `$skip` operation on documents for each user and not on the documents of all users. So I want something like:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            user_id: "$user_id",
            creation_time: "$creation_time"
        }
    },
    $sort: {
        user_id:1,
        creation_time:1
    },
    $skip: 4
}
```

But it seems that mongo db doesn't support it. I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Printing Stack Trace
    at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:7)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:897:1)
    at (shell):1:11
Mon Jul  1 14:47:55.762 JavaScript execution failed: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.",
    "code" : 16435,
    "ok" : 0
} at  src/mongo/shell/collection.js:L898
```

Comment: Why do you use the `$ceation_time` in the `group`? Isn't possible many documents to have the same user_id but different creation times?

Comment: @Schaliasos If I don't use `$creation_time`, then it groups all the documents of a user in one row. But I want all the documents for a user so that I can further do operations (sort and skip) on those documents. Now the question arises is that what's the significance of this grouping as the end result will be the same. So the answer for that question is that I want to perform `sort` and `skip` on all documents per user and not on all documents of all users. I thought of grouping them first by `user_id` so that further operations can be done. You can suggest if you have a better idea than that.

Comment: Then perhaps you don't really need the `group` statement.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Try first to order them, and then group them.

Comment: sorting first won't solve the problem because `group` operation ignores sorting before it.

Comment: @AntonioOtero I think you haven't got the question. I want to sort and  skip per group so doing `$sort` and `$skip` before `$group` will not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this currently in the aggregation framework.

You need to make a separate query for each user.  The best you can do is something that loops over all users executing a query for each to give you the documents that are not top 4:

```
[user list].forEach(function(u) { 
 var listToArchive = db.newsdb.find({user_id: u},{_id:1}).sort({creation_time:-1}).skip(4);
 /* do what you need to with listToArchive _id's */
} )
```

Comment: It can also be done with mapreduce but it's likely that multiple queries (if indexed) will be significantly faster than mapreduce on the entire collection.

Comment: If it makes sense to embed four documents you want to keep into user_id object, you can take advantage of 2.4 feature that lets you maintain capped arrays - each user can have array of four most recent documents - this also simplifies clean-up as it's done automatically when you insert a newer document into their array.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking too much, I figured out a solution using map-reduce since use aggregation framework seems to be not possible.

Here are the reduce function, that simple group documents by `user_id`.

```
var mapf = function () {
    emit(this.user_id, {
        _id: this._id,
        creation_time: this.creation_time
    })
}
```

On reduce function, I check if there is at least four entries. If true, `values` array is sorted by `creation_time` and the first 4 documents are skipped.

```
var redf = function (key, values) {
    var result = {};
    if (values.length > 4) {
        values.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.creation_time > b.creation_time;
        });

        // unfortunately, mongodb doesn't support array as result of reduce function
        result['oids'] = values.slice(3);
    } 

    return result;
}
```

Now it's time to run map-reduce command. The results will be inserted in `plus_four_users` collection.

```
db.newsdb.mapReduce(mapf, redf, { out : "plus_four_users" })
```

This will result in something like that:

```
> db.newsdb.find({}, { user_id : 1, creation_time : 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d612423dab6225ca6e6d36"), "creation_time" : 100, "user_id" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d612503dab6225ca6e6d37"), "creation_time" : 200, "user_id" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d612553dab6225ca6e6d38"), "creation_time" : 300, "user_id" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d612593dab6225ca6e6d39"), "creation_time" : 400, "user_id" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d6125d3dab6225ca6e6d3a"), "creation_time" : 500, "user_id" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d6126f55ebf2ff5a13d1c9"), "creation_time" : 600, "user_id" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d6127455ebf2ff5a13d1ca"), "creation_time" : 300, "user_id" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d6127955ebf2ff5a13d1cb"), "creation_time" : 400, "user_id" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d6127c55ebf2ff5a13d1cc"), "creation_time" : 500, "user_id" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d6127f55ebf2ff5a13d1cd"), "creation_time" : 600, "user_id" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d6128555ebf2ff5a13d1ce"), "creation_time" : 700, "user_id" : 11 }



 > db.plus_four_users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id": 10,
    "value": {
        "oids": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("51d6125d3dab6225ca6e6d3a"),
                "creation_time": 500
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("51d6126f55ebf2ff5a13d1c9"),
                "creation_time": 600
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id": 11,
    "value": {
        "oids": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("51d6128555ebf2ff5a13d1ce"),
                "creation_time": 700
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope that can help you!

Comment: it's true this can be done with map-reduce but your implementation is not correct.  As a simple test, try to run it with a sample data set where one user_id happens to have only one document.  It's also not going to work correctly on very large data set, and it will definitely break on a sharded collection.

Comment: You're right @AsyaKamsky. The problem with this MR function is the lack of Idempotence on reduce function. Actually, Yatendra Goel made some moodifications and found the solution, available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485957/mongodb-map-reduce-complete-data-is-not-returned

Comment: actually I gave him the solution here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/EhNEbyB9UBA/YgwELC3e91sJ